# Mapnik failing through a webstack

Tags: python, mapnik

I've inherited a pretty large / complex (internal) web portal (run under python 2.6.6), which has some mapping capabilities, using Mapnik 2.2.0.  The web service has recently started throwing 500 errors when it tries to create some of the maps that are displayed, with the sole error:

```
$ Premature end of script headers: app.wsgi
```

The maps are generated from geojson that is passed as a string (having been created from a python dictionary); I've tracked it down to 1 line of code in a `map.py`, which adds a layer to a map:

```
data = mapnik.Ogr(file=json, layer='OGRGeoJSON')
```

when I comment out that line of code (and the associated `m.layers[-1].data = data`) then the image is displayed on the portal, but obviously without this layer.  The json is valid (I have checked it on http://geojsonlint.com).

---

### Debugging efforts

#### Using a separate json file

I wanted to see whether calling the JSON from an external source replicated the problem.  I therefore saved the json string as a separate file (`test.json`), in the same directory as `map.py`, and modified the `Ogr` call to

```
data = mapnik.Ogr(file='test.json', layer='OGRGeoJSON')
```

I still get a 500 error, but with a slightly more verbose error message:

```
datasource = mapnik.Ogr(file='testgeo.json', layer='OGRGeoJSON')
File /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mapnik/__init__.py, line 536, in Ogr
return CreateDatasource(keywords)
RuntimeError: OGR Plugin: Failed to read GeoJSON data
```

---

#### Checking the geojson

```
$ ogrinfo testgeo.json
ERROR 4: GeoJSON Driver doesn't support update.
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `testgeo.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.
1: OGRGeoJSON (3D Polygon)
```

So the json seems valid

---

#### Using the python command line

I have also tried running python interactively ***in the same directory as `map.py` and `test.json`***:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mapnik
>>> mapnik.Ogr(file="testgeo.json", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
<mapnik.Datasource object at 0x7f6243c27398>
```

---

**Further info**

```
$ gdal-config --version
1.9.2

$ ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08
```

This returns with no errors (so I assume that this means the geojson is valid, confirming my earlier test of running the geojson through http://geojsonlint.com):

```
$ ogr2ogr testgeo.shp testgeo.json
```

OS Version

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Release:        6.7
Codename:       Final
```

---

These 3 debugging efforts show that the json **is** valid and that the call works, ***except*** when it's run through the webstack. I've checked the permissions and ownership of all relevant files and directories, and they all seem to be as I'd expect.

What else could be causing the issue?!

---

### Update (2 weeks after asking the original question)

I have come into work today and thought I'd have another crack at looking to see if I could tease some error messages out (new week, fresh start).  But, utterly bizarrely, the code does not seem to be failing (for now, at least).  I have changed *nothing*, and as far as I can gather, there have been no hardware changes to the servers.

This now becomes an investigation of what *did* cause it, and whether there's anything I can do to prevent it happening again...

Comment: I'm not a developer but at a first sight I see some difference in the OGR synthax definition of the json data (e.g. ' ' ' instead of ' " ').  Furthermore I remember that the OGR supported file extension is ".geojson" instead of  ".json". Hope it can help you in some way

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use an external file it **does** work (regardless of the file extension); it's when the json is embedded in the python as a string it has now stopped working

Comment: Have you checked, you use the same version of python/ mapnik scripts to execute mapnik.Ogr in the commandline and your webstack? Maybe there's a different implementation and an update could help?

Comment: Yes, it's Mapnik 2.2.0 and Python 2.6.6 in all cases

Comment: Is `file` a relative path? Maybe the server's work directory is somewhere else and so it doesn't find that, you could try adding the parameter `base="/home/geojsonfolder"` to the `mapnik.Ogr` call

Comment: @chrki I've tried that, and it still doesn't work.  Given that it doesn't work when the json is a string as well as when it's a file, I'd imagine that the location of a file isn't the problem

Comment: Maybe you could try running ogrinfo (or is it called gdalinfo ?) on the geojson file, and see if that throws any errors/warnings?

Comment: @til_b I've added the output from that command into my question

Comment: pretty weird. I don't have a mapnik install right now to check this. did you checked mapnik's issue tracker, to see if it's a known bug and there is a documented work around?

can't think of anything else.

Comment: @George Yeh, I've had a look through the github issues... :/

Comment: What is the OS that this is being deployed to? Once I had a weird bug going on, because of permissions. this was the rough structure:

folder A > folder B (where B is child of A).

Then, I had given all permissions to folder B, but not A. Since A was not accessible to the process, everything else failed (I had used -R as an option). If I'm not mistaken, this was on RHEL. Double check that, perhaps, it's a thing.

Comment: @George OS info added to the question

Comment: CentOS should have/behave in a similar fashion. Can you check what I suggested in the earlier comment?

Comment: @George all the folders in the web environment are 755, and have the same owner

Comment: I second the concern about permissions--just because the folder is 755/same owner, what about that particular file? This is especially suspect if the file has been modified or replaced shortly before this error occurred.

Comment: Also--you can watch your Apache error log in real time if you use this command:  `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`  The thinking is, fire off that command in a terminal window, then try to request the layer through your app; watch what appears in the log.

Comment: @elrobis The file definitely has the correct permissions too (My question does say that I'd already checked that)

Comment: @elrobis the only errors that are appearing in the log file are the ones I've put in my question

Comment: Utterly bizarrely, trying it again this morning has worked. I have changed _nothing_ :/ as far as I can work out, there's been no change to hardware on the server

Answer (score 2):

wait, it looks like it's expecting a file or a file-like object. when you say you have an json embedded in python, it's the whole json text, not the file path?

```
a = "/home/george/boundaries.json" # file-path
b = "{
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs': {
      'type': 'name',
      'properties': {
        'name': 'EPSG:3857'
      }
    },
    'features': [{
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [0, 0]
      }
    }, {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'LineString',
        'coordinates': [[4e6, -2e6], [8e6, 2e6]]
      }
    }]}" # json-content
```

Mapnik API it's expecting a file and it will open it up and parse it by itself.

Check the reference: http://mapnik.org/docs/v2.1.0/api/python/mapnik-module.html#Ogr

Copied from there, for completion:

```
from mapnik import Ogr, Layer
datasource = Ogr(base='/home/mapnik/data',file='rivers.geojson',layer='OGRGeoJSON') 
lyr = Layer('OGR Layer from GeoJSON file')
lyr.datasource = datasource
```

This link is for older docs (2.1) but my guess is that the API did not changed.

Of course, this is assuming, by your comments, that you're using option B, instead of A.

Comment: Sorry, my question obviously isn't clear enough. The original application *is* using a json string embedded within python - this stopped working. As part of my debugging efforts I extracted the json to make it use an external file. This only works when you call it on the python command line, but not through the webstack

Comment: oh ok. on a comment you said that it would always work on external files, regardless of extension. that's why I thought you were using the option B I showed in the answer.

Can you do an ogr2ogr to see if everything is ok with your json? What versions are your underlying libraries?

Comment: I meant that when I was testing with external files I didn't find any difference between whether the file extension was `.json` or `.geojson`; I've never used ogr2ogr - but it seems like it needs an input file, which I don't have. Which libraries should I be checking?

Comment: GDAL/OGR. try to convert your json file to let's say, a shapefile, using ogr2ogr.

if it all goes all right, it's a indication that the problem is not in GDAL/OGR, which is used by mapnik.

the permissions of the file are all ok? this comes down to debugging now. I once used mapnik in a webserver to generate a map, and never had this problem.